# Best method to close a keep-alive FTP or FTPS connection in C# (.NET 4.6)?

Tags: c#, ftp, keep-alive, ftps, .net-4.6

In C# (.NET 4.6) I am using a keep-alive FTPS connection to download a couple of files in a loop like this:

```
foreach (string filename in filenames)
{
  string requestUriString = GetFtpUriString(myDir) + "/" + filename;
  FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUriString);
  request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
  request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(myFtpsUsername, myFtpsPassword);
  request.EnableSsl = true;
  request.ConnectionGroupName = myConnectionGroupName;
  request.KeepAlive = true;

  ... do something ...
}
```

After the loop is done, I want to close the connection. I could not find a direct way to accomplish this. What I came up with is the following work-around, which makes another low-footprint request to the FTP server, this time with the `KeepAlive` flag set to `false`:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(GetFtpUriString(myDir));
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.PrintWorkingDirectory;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(myFtpsUsername, myFtpsPassword);
request.EnableSsl = true;
request.ConnectionGroupName = myConnectionGroupName;
request.KeepAlive = false;
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
response.Close();
```

I am wondering now whether there exists another, simpler, more elegant and direct way to close an open FTP connection for a specific connection group.

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The connection pool of `FtpWebRequest` instances does not have any public interface.

---

But there's an easy solution, just set the `KeepAlive` to `false` in the last round of the loop.

Comment: I considered this "solution" myself. In case of a `List` or similar collection it would be ok, but for a general "solution" using an arbitrary `IEnumerable` I consider it inferior to my "solution", because it would require the number of items in the enumeration to be known beforehand. In other words: If I do not want to loose the benefits of lazy evaluation for the loop's collection, I need to stick to my original "solution".