# FTP creationTimout error while transfering large files over FTP

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I'm transferring an updated program to the client through FTP server. The folder has a total size of 250 MB, I'm facing this problem.

> "System.Net.WebException: System error. ---> System.Net.InternalException: System error.
>   at System.Net.PooledStream.PrePush(Object expectedOwner) at System.Net.ConnectionPool.PutConnection(PooledStream pooledStream, Object owningObject, Int32 creationTimeout, Boolean canReuse)  at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.FinishRequestStage(RequestStage stage)  at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.SyncRequestCallback(Object obj)
>     at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.RequestCallback(Object obj) at System.Net.CommandStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)  at System.IO.Stream.Close()\r\n   at System.IO.Stream.Dispose()  at System.Net.ConnectionPool.Destroy(PooledStream pooledStream) at System.Net.ConnectionPool.PutConnection(PooledStream pooledStream, Object owningObject, Int32 creationTimeout, Boolean canReuse) at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.AttemptedRecovery(Exception e) at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.SubmitRequest(Boolean async)
>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>     at WMSUpdateManager.FTPManagerClass.getFileSizeOfDir(String filename) in C:\Users\USER\source\repos\WMSUpdateManager\WMSUpdateManager\FTPManagerClass.cs:line 472
>     at WMSUpdateManager.FTPManagerClass.getFileSize(String filename) in C:\Users\USER\source\repos\WMSUpdateManager\WMSUpdateManager\FTPManagerClass.cs:line 439   at WMSUpdateManager.FTPManagerClass.DownloadFileSet(String remoteFile, String localFile) in C:\Users\USER\source\repos\WMSUpdateManager\WMSUpdateManager\FTPManagerClass.cs:line 118"

I'm also using this block in a recursive function to get the directory size.

```
FtpWebRequest sizeRequest;

sizeRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + filename);
sizeRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
sizeRequest.UsePassive = true;
sizeRequest.KeepAlive = true;
sizeRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;
sizeRequest.UseBinary = true;
sizeRequest.EnableSsl = false;
sizeRequest.Timeout = -1;
FtpWebResponse respSize = (FtpWebResponse)sizeRequest.GetResponse();   //problem at line 472 
size = respSize.ContentLength;
sizeRequest = null;
respSize.Close();
```

[My log file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tNwPMFheJpD6WS-2FVCtjrhJOrsyKLHw/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Show us [log file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9664650/850848).

Comment: How large a file are you sending?  <10M,10M+, 20M+

Comment: @jdweng the file is  250 MB

Comment: Does the server limit the size of the transfer?  250MB sound like server may be dropping connection.  I would use sniffer and check TCP transport layer for a FIN.

Comment: @jdweng no I transferred the file using the filezella client successfully.
this code is called within the download operation.within that function I'm not even using this call recursively.
the download checks if it's a directory or a file then if file it downloads or if it's a directory it lists the files and calls itself for each one.  
the exception was catched in the downloading function.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I have attached the log file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the culprit:

> System.Net Information: 0 : [7640] FtpControlStream#54444047 - Received response [421 **No-transfer-time exceeded. Closing control connection.**]

Your FTP server closes your connection after some time, if you do not do any file transfer. "Size" requests likely do not count as "transfers".

---

What you can do is to force `FtpWebRequest` to open new connection, before the server closes the current one.

For example, this will make .NET open new connection every minute:

```
sizeRequest.ConnectionGroupName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm");
```

See also:

- [Best method to close a keep-alive FTP or FTPS connection in C# (.NET 4.6)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38855392/850848)
- [C# - FtpWebRequest - Multiple requests over the same connection/login](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37635406/850848#37639166)